# VBA Object Defined Error

Tags: excel, vba, object

I am getting a Run-Time Error '1004' based on the bottom line of code.  If I "end" and Re-run, the problem does not come up.

I have only included the relevant code as I have a lot of variables, if's and formatting code.

```
Dim Yeild As String
Sub NewPage()
              '...
Yeild = "=INDEX(AcreGrid,MATCH(" & Chr(34) & Comm & Chr(34) & _
          ",Prod!R3C1:R30C1,),MATCH(" & Chr(34)  & Season & Chr(34) & _
          ",Prod!R3C1:R3C16,))/" & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3)
              '... the above formula has been giving me the most problems
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Formula = "=Vlookup(B" & ActiveCell.Row & ", EQF,5,)" 'Factor
               '... I didn't define the above formula because it was causing problems
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 7) = Yeild
               '...
 End Sub
```

I have also tried the following but the Cell Reference B4 changes to 'B4'; causes a #NAME? error in Excel.

```
Yeild = "=INDEX(AcreGrid,MATCH(" & Chr(34) & Comm & Chr(34) & _
        ",Prod!R3C1:R30C1,),MATCH(" & Chr(34)  & Season & Chr(34) & _
        ",Prod!R3C1:R3C16,))/Vlookup(B" & ActiveCell.Row & ", EQF,5,)"
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 7) = Yeild
```

Any help would be greatly appriciated.

Comment: Move `Dim Yeild As String` into the sub. I would also put `Option Explicit` at the top of your module...

Comment: Thanks but no luck.  Same issue.

Comment: What's actually in `Yeild`?  Its probably not what you think.  Use a BreakPoint or `Debug.Print Yeild` to see what's actually there before you try to assign it into a Formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Minor stuff

Okay, first thing some nitpicking. I suggest being explicit and assign to `.Formula` or `.FormulaR1C1` instead of leaving it implied as you do on this line:

```
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 7) = Yeild
```

#### Likely Source of Error Message

Now for your actual problem. There are many places where the following line could go wrong and produce an invalid formula

```
Yeild = "=INDEX(AcreGrid,MATCH(" & Chr(34) & Comm & Chr(34) & ",Prod!R3C1:R30C1,),MATCH(" & Chr(34) & Season & Chr(34) & ",Prod!R3C1:R3C16,))/" & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3)
```

An easy example, if the last part of the statement `ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3)` returns blank or an error value you end up with a formula divided by nothing, or an error:

```
=INDEX(AcreGrid,MATCH("",Prod!R3C1:R30C1,),MATCH("",Prod!R3C1:R3C16,))/
```

That is not a valid formula because of the trailing division `/` at the end. So Excel gives you Run-time error 1004, which in this case means the same thing as the "Microsoft Excel found an error in the formula you entered." message, only less helpful or descriptive.

Another source of trouble could be if `Comm` or `Season` include any double quotes `"`.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it.  I had to move the order of variable definitions and `activecell` references.  I was also missing `application.calculate`.